# Subgroups which are not subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. Is every subgroup of the abelian group $\Bbb Z_p^2$ a subspace of it as a vector space over $\Bbb Z_p$?

Can it be generalized to all finite fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a prime field: yes.  Every proper, non-trivial subgroup is of order $p$ and therefore cyclic.  So, if $v$ generates this set, there is an isomorphism $\phi$ determined by $\phi(v) = (1,0)$.

Counterexample in the other case:

For [$\mathbb{F}_4$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=finite%20field%20of%20order%204), the subfield $\{0,1\}$ is not a vector subspace of $\mathbb{F}_4$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Since every finite field has prime characteristic, the subgroup generated by $1$ will always be a proper subfield.

Answer (score 2):

This is true of prime fields.

If the order of the field is not a prime, then you can find counterexamples already in One-dimensional spaces, and you should try.

Comment: "This is true *for* prime fields."?

Comment: A (finite) prime field is one with a prime number of elements.

Comment: It is more of a ELU question what I am asking.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff what does the English Lacrosse Union have to do with this?  Also, I think that *of* works fine here.